# Какая фигура речи противоположна гиперболе?

Tags: фигуры-речи, классификация

Гипербола - невероятное, чудовищное преувеличение. "У меня их наверху тысячи!" - говорил Карлсон о паровых машинах. Алиса же говорила так: "...тогда я уменьшусь до ниже пола". Вопроса, собственно, два:

1. Противоположна ли гиперболе фигура, использованная Алисой (невероятно сильное преуменьшение)?
2. Как называется такая фигура?

Если ответ на первый вопрос отрицателен, то каков пример фигуры, противоположной гиперболе? Как сформулировать идею этой фигуры, если это не невероятно сильное преуменьшение?

---

UPD. Итак, указание на невероятно малый размер - это **тоже гипербола**, потому что здесь качество (малость) не ослабляется, а усиливается. Противоположностью гиперболе должна быть фигура, в которой действительное качество **ослабляется**. То есть, если человек действительно очень маленький (карлик), назвать его "мужичок с ноготок" будет *преувеличением*, гиперболой; а противоположным определением будет что-то вроде "невысокий человек".

Эту *противоположную фигуру* преуменьшения, ослабления качества разные исследователи называют **литотой** или **мейозисом**. В некоторых случаях литоту называют разновидностью мейозиса. Откуда это пошло (кто первый придумал), пока что установить не удалось. Похоже, что все пути ведут к работам М.Ю.Скребнева.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы говорите о риторике или о стилистике? В стилистике часто путают эти понятия. В риторике более точно отграничивается гипербола от литоты и от мейозиса:гипербола - это художественный прием преувеличения, причем такого преувеличения, которое с точки зрения реальных возможностей осуществления мысли представляется сомнительным или просто невероятным.Гипербола преувеличивает большое и преуменьшает маленькое и тогда называется гиперболой преуменьшения, а по сути представляет преувеличение незначительности, ничтожности, что мы и наблюдаем в "Алисе".(Поэтому отрицателен ответ на вопрос, противоположен ли гиперболе этот троп.Это и есть гипербола, иногда говорят "гипербола наоборот")

мейозис (преуменьшение) - имеет место преуменьшение того, что в действительности является крупным  Это проявление сдержанности, вежливости:"Ваше утверждение не совсем правильно"(на самом деле неправильное).

литота - (вид мейозиса) - утверждение через отрицание противоположной идеи,намеренное ослаблении говорящим признака или свойства, о котором идет речь . Достигается с помощью двойного отрицания: не без умысла = скорее с умыслом, небесполезный = отчасти полезный. Такие высказывания являются смягченной формой выражения несогласия с собеседником:
"Не думаю, что вы правы" (В смысле — "Думаю, что вы неправы").
[http://is.park.ru/doc.jsp?urn=55553478
novsu.ru/file/799798.](http://is.park.ru/doc.jsp?urn=55553478%20novsu.ru/file/799798)

Итак,гипербола – сильное преувеличение размеров(и больших, и маленьких);
литота (простота) – обратная гипербола, образное выражение, намеренно преуменьшающее размер, силу, красоту.(на самом деле больший);мейозис (то же, что и литота) – фигура речи, преуменьшающая свойства, степень чего-либо.

Comment: Я бы сказал, идеальный ответ! И гораздо чётче, понятнее приведённых в нём ссылок; в статьях по ссылкам только всё лишний раз запутывается.

-------------

Остаётся вопрос: откуда всё-таки возникла идея, что литота - разновидность мейозиса? В сети я нахожу лишь кучу рефератов, цитирующих эту идею в качестве аксиомы.

Comment: По-моему, как раз это ясно: мейозис - преуменьшение в какой-то степени свойств вообще, литота-преуменьшение свойств с помощью отрицания. В стилистике, возможно, путаница со словом "преуменьшить"- представить в меньших размерах, чем на самом деле, а мы по аналогии с "преувеличить" представляем как "очень уменьшить", а такого значения у слова нет.Это не очень уменьшить, а слегка.Очень - уже гипербола.

Comment: Людмила, как понимать Вашу фразу о том, что в стилистике "путают понятия"?
Известные мне определения никак не зависят от сферы применения термина. А если кто-то неправильно их употребляет, то это проблема не стилистики и не риторики, а личное дело автора.  
И, поскольку Карфаген таки должен быть разрушен, повторю. Терминологические споры бессодержательны.  
//---------------   
>откуда всё-таки возникла идея, что литота - разновидность мейозиса?  
Из определений этих терминов. Замените "разновидность" на "частный случай", так понятнее будет?

Comment: >Поэтому отрицателен ответ на вопрос, противоположен ли гиперболе этот троп.Это и есть гипербола, иногда говорят "гипербола наоборот"  

Весьма странное заявление. Из Вами сказанного вытекает как раз то, что ответ как раз положительный. Ну может не "диаметрально противоположен", но процентов эдак на 90. 10% - на то, что полностью противоположен мейосис, а литота - это его частный случай, против чего и вы не возражаете.

Comment: Вы не очень внимательно прочитали комментарий. В стилистике "мужичок с ноготок" называют мейозисом (литотой), а в риторике - только гиперболой, потому что там преувеличены до невозможного маленькие размеры человека.Это гипербола преуменьшения.А мейозис и литота - из области эвфемизма, чтобы не обидеть, преуменьшим размер неприятного: вместо "он глуп" - мейозис "он глуповат" и литота "он не совсем умён".

Comment: > откуда всё-таки возникла идея, что литота - разновидность мейозиса?
> 
> \- Из определений этих терминов. 

Ceterum censeo (в четвёртый раз!): дайте ссылку на **определения этих терминов** - на словарь (энциклопедию, справочник), где *литота* определяется как *разновидность мейозиса*.

Comment: @stopkran, я придерживаюсь мнения, что просить что-то более двух раз неприлично. Особенно, когда требуемое лежит на поверхности. 

>В стилистике "мужичок с ноготок" называют мейозисом (литотой), а в риторике - только гиперболой...

Допустим, хотя утверждение само по себе спорно. Про "гиперболу наоборот" я тоже прекрасно понимаю. Но вопрос был в том, почему данный троп НЕ является противоположностью гиперболе. Если не влезать в философию...
 
>Вы не очень внимательно прочитали комментарий  
Гм... Вы уверены?

Comment: @behemothus, мне не совсем понятна ваша апелляция к приличиям. Пруфлинк - элементарное требование формата Ответов, он лежит не в ряду "приличный - культурный - интеллигентный", а совсем в другой плоскости: "доказал" - "не доказал".

> Но вопрос был в том, почему данный троп НЕ является противоположностью гиперболе

Ответ лежит на поверхности. Точнее, в основном тексте ответа @Людмилы.

Comment: Словари и энциклопедии на Академике
http://text_analysis.academic.ru/230/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B
 К основным тропам относят:
  1) метонимию;
  2) метафору;
  3) иронию;
  4) гиперболу;
  5) мейозис.
  Выделяются их разновидности: литота, синекдоха, олицетворение [Скребнев 1997: 572].

Comment: http://www.litobuch.narod.ru/kulturarechi3.html
9) Разновидностью мейозиса является литота — образное выражение, содержащее преуменьшение, ослабление свойства, качества, явления до немыслимых в реальности размеров (мальчик с пальчик, мужичок с ноготок; В двух шагах живу от школы).

Comment: Взаимодействие гиперболы, мейозиса и литоты :http://is.park.ru/doc.jsp?urn=55553478 
Учебно-методический комплекс по дисциплине «риторика» Учебно-методический комплекс Составитель: к ф. н., доцент
http://rudocs.exdat.com/docs/index-395860.html?page=12Литота является разновидностью мейозиса (от греч. meiosis - уменьшение, убывание). Мейозис представляет собой троп, заключающийся в преуменьшении интенсивности свойств (признаков) предметов, явлений, процессов: «ничего себе», «сойдет», «приличный», «терпимый» (о хорошем), «неважный», «вряд ли пригодный», «оставляющий желать лучшего» (о плохом).

Comment: @Людмила, вот до этого места - **[Скребнев 1997: 572]** - я и сам дошёл в поисках :-). Меня интересует именно расшифровка: что же написал д-р Скребнев в 1997 году и где бы это можно было почитать?

----------------

По второй ссылке всё плохо. "Ослабление свойста" ну никак не вяжется с "до немыслимых в реальности размеров". *Мужичок с ноготок* - это не ослабление (преуменьшение), а усиление, преувеличение; вы же в своём ответе совершенно правильно определили это как "гиперболу наоборот".

Comment: Вы иссякли?
Поскольку для меня фраза "вы невнимательно читаете" очевидно характеризует говорящего куда больше чем того, к кому обращаются, посмею высказаться, что никаких доводов за то, что литота не является противоположностью гиперболе я тут не увидел. Всё ценное, что можно почерпнуть, - идея о том, что все действительно может зависеть от точки зрения (то бишь сферы рассмотрения). Чтобы понять, в чем вещи различаются противоположны надо указать, в чем они схожи. Но это вопрос философский.

Answer (score 4):

~1. Если бы это было просто преуменьшение ("до пола"), то можно было бы считать противоположностью гиперболе. Здесь - доведение не просто до крайности, здесь - через край (ниже пола), т.е. скорее *катахреза*: употребление сочетания слов во взаимоисключающих лексических значениях. 
Впрочем, очень многие тропы на самом деле являются комбинированными, указать на троп в в чистом виде не просто. Думаю, будет справедливо назвать троп, использованный Алисой, и *мейозисом* или *литотой* т.е. "гиперболой наоборот", и *иронией*, и *апагогией* - доведением до абсурда,  и даже *анаколуфом* - умышленном нарушением грамматической (синтаксической) связи.
Без всего этого Алиса просто не была бы Алисой.

~2. если строго, то противоположность гиперболе - мейосис. Литоту можно рассматривать как его частный случай.

//---
Интересно, а каким образом мой ответ стал приписан сообществу?
Я понимаю модераторскую правку, но такое...
Вынужден восстановить справедливость

Comment: Ну, вот это уже более основательно (в т.ч. про комбинирование фигур). Я тоже где-то встречал версию "литота - разновидность мейозиса". Но теперь никак не могу найти источника в интернете.

Вы не могли бы дать ссылку на источник (можно и на бумажную книгу)?

Comment: Очень подробный анализ.

Очень солидная подпись.

Но без пруфлинка.

Comment: Есть такой сборник: Межвузовский сборник научных трудов. - Ростов: Изд-во Ростовского университета, 1987. 3 . ...Скребнев Ю.М. Тропы и фигуры как объект классификации // Проблемы . У меня его нет, если Вам так необходимо - смотрите в научной библиотеке. Ничем помочь не могу.Риторикой вообще не очень увлекаюсь. А в лингвистике эти понятия смешивают, тропы не различают, учеников не путают. Всё, что преувеличено, -гипербола.Что уменьшено - литота(синоним мейозис). В большой науке разграничивают, а как и где - надо искать, у меня нет желания и времени.

Comment: Ну, ничего страшного, я ведь и не настаиваю, чтобы вы искали. Вы уже нашли автора (и даже выходные данные сборника), спасибо.

Comment: 1987 - очень далеко. Тогда все еще только начиналось в терминологии тропов. И до сих пор единства нет.

Comment: >1987 - очень далеко...   

Дык для троллинга все сгодится.  
Сам по себе тезис самоочевиден, какой нужен еще источник, если есть элементарная логика. *Если гипербола - преувеличение чего-либо, а литота - "преувеличение минимальности", то литота - частный случай гиперболы.* И "без никаких" сборников.  

Вот кто бы действительно внятно объяснил, почему одно не есть противоположность другому...

Comment: Так уж принято в научной терминологии, не только в лингвистике.

Answer (score 3):

Такая фигура называется  **литота**.

Добавляю:
Литота - вид тропа, «обратная гипербола»; приём выразительности речи, намеренное преуменьшение малых размеров предмета речи: мужичок с ноготок, мальчик с пальчик, от горшка два вершка, одну секундочку!, в двух шагах отсюда; «Ваш шпиц, прелестный шпиц, не более напёрстка. Я гладил всё его; как шёлковая шёрстка» (Грибоедов).
 Как приём выразительности речи Л.- «обратная гипербола» — активно используется в разг. речи, в художественной и публицистической лит-ре.
[link text](http://russkiyyazik.ru/476/)

Comment: Какова сущность этой фигуры? "невероятно сильное преуменьшение"?

Comment: Именно так

Comment: Однако по ссылке, данной @Элен, мы видим на первом месте совершенно другое значение:

> **Литота** (от греч. litotes — простота, сдержанность) - 1) вид тропа (см.), приём выразительности речи, заключающийся в намеренном ослаблении говорящим признака или свойства, о к-ром идёт речь. Достигается с помощью двойного отрицания: не без умысла, небесполезный...

Comment: Но Вы спрашивали, не что такое литота, а как называется фигура, противоположная гипербола. Я, отвечая на вопрос, опустила первую часть. Кстати, если бы меня спросили, что такое литота, я бы ответила: преуменьшение. Про первое значение я не очень-то и знала.

Comment: Кстати, считаю, что Вам следует засчитать мой ответ как правильный. )))

Comment: Может, и засчитаю, попозже. Посмотрим пока: может, кто-нибудь про мейозис ещё что-нибудь напишет (например, энциклопедию "Русский язык" процитирует).

Comment: В том-то и дело, что вопрос достаточно спорный. По сути - что считать противоположностью преувеличения: преуменьшение малого или "смягчение", ослабление свойства, эвфемизм? И в употреблении терминов есть расхождения в разных источниках.

Comment: @Элен, по Вашей ссылке - весьма сомнительный источник, непонятно кем составленный и изданный. Поэтому легкая путаница со значениями и формулировками не удивительна. 
на самом деле "первое значение" отнюдь не противоречит второму (реально - основному), просто является одним из его частных случаев. И, конечно же, предложенный прием (названный авторами "двойное отрицание", что уже само по себе спорно) - не единственный для подобного тропа. 
Сравните, например, [здесь][1].

[1]: http://ped_recheved.academic.ru/107/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0